# How to Host a microservice webapp in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I have a microservice architecture web application that I need to host in AWS in a cheap and optimized manner.

I have 3 spring boot applications and two node applications. My Application used MySql Database.

Following is my plan:

1. Get 1 EC2 instance.
2. Get RDS for mySql DB.
3. Install docker on EC2.
4. create 2 docker containers.
   a. One tomcat container to run all spring boot applications.
   b. one container to run node applications.

Q1. Is it possible to deploy my application in this manner, or am I inherently flawed in my understanding of AWS architecture?

Q2. Do I need a 3rd Nginx docker container?

Q3. is there anything else required?

Any Help is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, the current design is good to begin with keeping in mind you want to have the economy in mind. You have isolated your datastore by moving it to RDS.

**Q1.** Yes, I think your approach is fine. But this would mean you will have to take care of the provisioning of the EC2 instance and RDS instance on your own. You can also try to explore Elastic Beanstalk if you want to offload all this to AMZ. The tech stack that you are currently using is supported by Elastic Beanstalk and you may find it a little difficult to begin with but later will prove to be beneficial.

**Q2.** I would say yes. You should have a separate NGINX container.

**Q3.** You must also try to containerize each Spring Boot application instead of having just one docker container hosting all of them. And same goes true for your 2 Node applications too. Once you have dockerized all the application you then have complete isolation of the application and can handle the resiliency & scaling part much better than keeping them together.

I hope this answers your query.

Comment: Thanks piy26. For further clarification, is it necessary to create an ECS cluster for achieving the above?

Comment: For dev purposes and to keep things simple, you can skip using ECS. For now you can just have docker installed on your EC2 instance and run all applications i.e. 3 Boot and 2 Node application on that single EC2 instance (all this if you are not using BeanStalk). ECS will help when you would want to have production deployment of your application. That's why I suggest to keep all your applications containerized so that your transition would be easier when you move to production using ECS or related service.

Comment: **all this if you are not using BeanStalk** can I use beanstalk to achieve the same? Is there any specific advantage?